# Is there a way to open Default email client on Phonegap like using the href="tel:" method?

Tags: cordova

I saw the plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#examples but i am wondering if there any way to click a href like the call function `href="tel:1234543"` and it opens up the screen that allows you to select email apps on your phone? As i dont need the email to be sent in App.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you can use mailto

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.com">Link text</a>
```

You might have to add this line to the config.xml

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Comment: This feature works fine but it also show some non email apps in popup, is there any option to open only email apps in popup. Like in android we can set mime type.

Comment: That  apps might have register that they can handle mails. Anyway, if you know how to do it for Android, just create a plugin with that code. On iOS mailto will use the default iOS app